# How to fire button click automatically when page is load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

I have included given code

```
<div class="tab-control">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#aggregated">Aggregated</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#app">App</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#operator">Operator</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#top">Top<br>by User</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#total">Total</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#session">Sessions</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="frames">
    <div class="frame" id="app">
      welcome app
      <div class="time">yola</div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame" id="operator">
      welcome operator
      <div class="time">yola</div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame" id="aggregated">
      welcome aggregated
      <div class="time">yola</div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame" id="top">
      Thankyou top
      <div class="time">yola</div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame" id="total">
      Exact Total
      <div class="time">yola</div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame" id="session">
      Your session
      <div class="time">yola</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in my js I have written this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tab-control').tabcontrol().bind("tabcontrolchange", function(event, frame) {
  switch($(frame).attr('id')) {
    case "operator":
      break;
    case "aggregated":
      $('.time').text('aggregates')
      break;
    case "app":
      $('.time').text('app')
      break;
    case "top":
      $('.time').text('top')
      break;
    case "total":
      $('.time').text('total')
      break;
    case "session":
      $('.time').text('session')
      break;
  }
});
})
```

But when page load it shows at that time aggregated tab is active and it shows
`<div class="time">yola</div>` and when I click on this tab then it changes to 
`<div class="time">aggregates</div>` So I need when my page get loads at that time it automatically clicks on tab. Please dont give me that answer I will set in my `<div class="time">aggregates</div>` as my requirement is different. Thanks in advance

Comment: Whatever `tabcontrol()` plugin or method is, i guess you should check the relevant DOC. Trigger event is simple but you'd have better to use instead relevant plugin method, if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand, you want to click on the first tab list-item link?

If that's the case, then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs a').first().click();
});
```

Comment: Yes I want this when page gets load after loading it automatically fire click function. I had tried above code its not working

Comment: @dinshawraje, Samuel Liew's code is correct. May be the click event triggered before your plugin generating the tabs. So, just try this  setTimeout(function(){$('.tabs a').first().click();},500);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, what you want is to run the click event one first time on document.ready and without any click.

I recommend you to name your function and recall it twice

```
$(document).ready(NameofFunction(event, $('.frame #aggregated') ));
$(#yourButton).on("click", NameofFunction(event, frame));
```

...mmmmaybe? ^^